# Force jQuery to change animation while running

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I am creating a jQuery drop down menu with a custom animation, and the menu should start the animation when the mouse enters, and start the closing animation when the mouse leaves, regardless of any running animations. The problem is that jQuery completes the animation before starting the new one. For example;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#start").mouseenter(function(){
    $("#box").toggle();
    $("#box").animate({
      top:'50px',
      opacity:'1'
    },500,function(){
    });
  });
  $("#start").mouseleave(function(){
    $("#box").animate({
      top:'25px',
      opacity:'0'
    },500,function(){
    $("#box").toggle();
    });
  });
});
</script> 
</head>

<body>
<button id="start">Start Animation</button>
<div id ="box" style="background:#e6e6e6;height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;opacity:0;display:none;top:25px;">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

How would I approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.stop()` befor you starting animation.
It will stop previous animation.

eq.

```
$("#box").stop().animate({...})
```

and the same before `.toggle()`

```
$("#box").stop().toggle();
```